# リストに含まれる変数の値をfor文で変更したい

Tags: python, python3

変数をリストとしてまとめ、その要素となる変数の値を変更したいです。
(Python3.5.2)

以下コードを考えましたが想定通り機能しません。

```
import sys

aa = 10
bb = 10
cc = 10
dd = 10

attributes = [aa, bb, cc, dd]

for attribute in attributes:
    print(attribute)
    attribute = attribute - 1
    print(attribute)

print(attributes)
```

が、実行したところ、for文のスコープ外では値がもとに戻ります。

```
10
9
10
9
10
9
10
9
[10, 10, 10, 10]
```

最後のprint(attributes)が返す値が[9, 9, 9, 9]となるようにしたいです。
おそらくグローバル等変数のスコープを見直せばよいとは考えておりますが、具体的にわかりません。
また、そもそもこの書き方が「Pythonらしい」書き方なのかどうかかもわかっておりません。
その点も合わせてご教示いただけると助かります。

Comment: 確認なのですが、リスト`attributes`の中身は代入時点での変数`aa`〜`dd`の値であって、変数`aa`〜`dd`自体ではありません。そのため、`attributes`の要素の値は変数(への参照)ではなく単に整数です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attribute`は`attributes`の要素の参照ではなくコピーになるので，`attribute`を変更してもその変更は`attributes`の要素には伝わりません．
直接`attributes`の要素を変更してやる必要があります．
なので，`enumerate`を使って

```
for i, attribute in enumerate(attributes):
    attributes[i] = attribute-1
```

とするか，`len`を使って

```
for i in range(len(attributes)):
    attributes[i] = attributes[i]-1
```

とすれば動くはずです．
もしくはこの程度の小さいコードであればリスト内包表記を使って記述したほうが簡潔になります．その場合は次のように書きます．

```
attributes = [attribute-1 for attribute in attributes]
```

Comment: おっと，そうです．`range`を使う必要がありました．修正しました．

Comment: 早速の返信ありがとうございます。`range(len(attributes)):`の方式で求める動作が確認できました。リスト内砲表記はまた別途挑戦してみます。